# How to align sublists and lists using enumitem correctly?

Tags: align, itemize, enumitem, alignment

I'm trying to configure aligning of lists and sublists using `enumitem`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Lists:

\begin{itemize}[align=left, labelindent=0em, leftmargin=0em, itemindent=!, nosep, noitemsep]
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  %
  \begin{itemize}[nosep, noitemsep]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \end{itemize}
  %
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Labels are placed correctly, but the 1st lvl text start (1 and 5 lines) should align according to the 2nd lvl label (3 line), and the 2nd lvl text continuation (4 line) should align according to the 2nd lvl label (3 line) too. How can I achieve that? I tried to read https://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf, but it's all Greek to me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Only 3 arrows on the screen should be changed, 2nd, 3rd and 6th lines are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Hopefully now my suggestion gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,
                  align=left, 
                  labelwidth=1em, labelsep=0.5em, leftmargin=0em,
                  itemindent=!
                  }
\setlist[itemize,2]{wide,
                    leftmargin=1.5em
                  }

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Lists:

\begin{itemize} 
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  %
  \begin{itemize} 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \end{itemize}
  %
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need the 2nd and the 4th line in your screen to be aligned according to their labels, i.e. "por" right under the dot and "tempor" right under the dash. The same is for the 6th line.

Comment: @cppbest, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although these parameters didn't exactly fit my real use case, I managed to brute force them using your answer. And ofc it's correct as an answer to this particular question.